# Deploying node.js app to Heroku - "No gruntfile found."

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, yeoman, mean-stack

I'm trying to deploy a MEAN stack app to Heroku and am running into trouble when it tries to find 'gruntfile.js.' The relevant logs follow:

*Caching node_modules directory for future builds

Cleaning up node-gyp and npm artifacts

No Procfile found; Adding npm start to new Procfile

Building runtime environment

**No Gruntfile (grunt.js, Gruntfile.js, Gruntfile.coffee) found**

Discovering process types

Procfile declares types -> web*

Compressing... done, 17.8MB
Launching... done, v11

I do have 'gruntfile.js' in the root of my folder structure along with package.json, etc. I'm not exactly sure why Heroku is unable to find it, but it seems to be the likely culprit for why the app is crashing.

**Other potentially relevant details:**

The app is scaffolded using Yeoman and generator-mean (https://github.com/jrcryer/generator-mean).

I'm using a custom buildpack on Heroku (https://github.com/mbuchetics/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-grunt) which I came across while researching this issue.

Comment: So I'm unable to answer this question myself, as my reputation is too low. I think Heroku looks for "Gruntfile.js" instead of "gruntfile.js." When I changed the name to "grunt.js" it recognized it immediately...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux servers are case sensitive when it comes to file names, so as ArloWilkinson above mentioned, make sure that your casing is correct on `Gruntfile.js`

Answer (score 0):

I think we changed it to Gruntfile about 2 monthes ago.
What version of mean are you running?